# how to disable user in Apache Directory Ldap

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap

Iam using Apache Directory Ldap. I started using it just recently. I had one query:

I had one attribute called 'user-last-date', so as soon as this user end-date reaches, I should be able to disable the user account in ldap and also should send out an automated email to his manager. So, Is that possible to disable the user automatically in ldap as soon as the 'user-last-date' reached?

I already searched in google on this, not finding much info on this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible by default, however you can write a custom interceptor to achieve this.
Or you can set the value of attribute pwdAccountLockedTime to 000001010000Z to permanently lock the account, but this will be effective only if the passwordpolicy is enabled.

Comment: The attribute pwdAccountLockedTime seems to be password related attribute, but in my case account shouldnt be locked because of some login failed attempt trails. So, is there any such similar attribute in apache directory related to account disabling/locking ?